# How to pass an ID/parameter to ROR controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In view I have a link as follow in "teacher" controller. this link supposed to send an id to another controller "teacher_details" (1 to 1 relationship). This link open a webpage to add more details about teacher.

```
<%= link_to 'Add details', new_teacher_detail_path(@teacher), :id => "add_detail_link" %>
```

My controller code is

```
private
def set_teacher
  @teachers = Teacher.find(params[:id])
end
```

When I run this code it shows me an error that "cannot find with out an ID". What am I doing wrong. The link does not passing the id parameter properly.

Route file is

```
root 'sessions#login'
  get 'homes/home'
  get '/login' => "sessions#login", :as => "login"
  get '/logout' => "sessions#logout", :as => "logout"
  get '/homes' => "homes#home"
  resources :users
  resources :sessions
  resources :homes
  resources :teachers
  resources :teacher_details
  resources :profiles
```

Comment: Show your routes file, how have you define your routes for `new_teacher_detail_path`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not nesting TeacherDetail with Teacher model in routing.

That's why it not getting any `id` parameter in `new_teacher_detail_path`. So you can't find `params[:id]` in below action.

```
private
  def set_teacher
    @teachers = Teacher.find(params[:id])
  end)
```

Try change Your link_to as below :

```
<%= link_to 'Add details', new_teacher_detail_path(:id => @teacher.id), :id => "add_detail_link" %>
```

Now you will get ID parameter properly.

Comment: I tried with nesting, still having trouble with parameter passing. though it worked fine with user and profile. How should I do it? pls help

Comment: I have updated my answer you will get Id properly now. Without nesting

Answer (score 0):

Routes file for teacher and details should be like this:

```
resources :teachers do
   get 'details/new', on: :member
end
```

Then in view you can use link_to like this

```
<%= link_to 'Add details', details_new_teacher(@teacher) %>
```

No need to change in controller

Answer (score 0):

In one-to-one relationship `teacher_detail` has `foreign_key` as `teacher_id`, So you can use like this

```
<%= link_to 'Add details', new_teacher_detail_path(id: @teacher.id), :id => "add_detail_link" %>
```